# Remote connection to a MySQL DB from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, connection-pooling, remote-connection

I need to connect to a MySQL remote database from my eclipse project.

I change my context.xml in this way:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/aname" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
          username="userdb" password="pwddb" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://ipaddress/dbname" 
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" />
```

I use a ConnectionPool and in the lookup I use

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/aname");
```

I don't succeed in connecting to the db. I obtain this exception:

```
Unexpected exception resolving reference
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2332)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor22.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:175)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:470)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:135)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:112)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:99)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:501)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:224)
at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at mypackage.login.LoginValidatorAction.execute(LoginValidatorAction.java:44)
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:294)
... 61 more

javax.naming.NamingException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:860)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at mypackage.login.LoginValidatorAction.execute(LoginValidatorAction.java:44)
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**EDIT**

I found out that ny mysql db hosting doesn't allow connections from out of its network

Comment: Try to specify your mysql port ind datsource jdbc url

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov: In url="jdbc:mysql://ipaddress/dbname"? url="jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:3306/dbname" for example? I tried and it doesn't work. Via php I succeed in accessing the db, with that parameters, so I don't think it's a port problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying a test project to make sure you can remotely connect. Below is a sample of code that should work - you need to specify your Ipaddress, username, password, and the database name you wish to connect to which I marked in between the brackets. Ensure that the username for the MySQL database has remote access privileges ( something like GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON exampledb.* TO username@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; ) Note that the '%' specifies that the connection can come from ANY IP-address.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class JDBCExample {

public static void main(String[] argv) throws SQLException {

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    System.out.println("-------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------");

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }

    System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.8:3306/[DATABASE_NAME_HERE]",
                        "[YOUR_USERNAME]", "[YOUR_PASSWORD]");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

            /*
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    boolean result = stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE Students " +
            " (student_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
            " PRIMARY KEY (student_ID), firstName varchar(255), " +
            " lastName varchar(255))");
    System.out.println("\tTable creation result: " + result + "\t");
    System.out.println("**Note: The expected result is FALSE");
            */
}
}
```

Edit: This solution works for a MySQL 5.5 install using InnoDB engine, running on a Linux server. The above code is run from Eclipse with the Connector/J .jar files included in the build-path in the project properties - just to clarify.

Comment: test done, the result is the string -------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------
MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!
Connection Failed! Check output console
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: Do you have access to the server running the MySQL database? If so on the command line run "mysql --version" and check the distribution number; check your mysql configuration file (/etc/mysql/my.cnf) and ensure that mysqld is set to listen on port 3306; and again you need to make sure that your mysql user is privileged for remote access. Then try "sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart" to reload the mysql server process. You are running all of this on the same local network as the server I assume, just from a different machine?

Comment: The answer is your last question... I found out that my mysql db hosting doesn't allow connections from out of its network. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try to find out if ssh tunneling is supported.